# How to select randomly multiple items, with replacement, from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array with all letters of the alphabet plus full stop and space. What I want to do is select randomly a large number of these letters (it does not matter if the same letter gets selected more than once) and print them on the screen. What I've got this far is this:

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ".", " "];

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var random_letter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28);
    var result = [];
    result[i] = [letters[random_letter]];
    document.write(result);
}
```

However, when I run the script in Firefox I get this output:

```
X,C,,N,,,A,,,,T,,,,,.,,,,,,N,,,,,,,T,,,,,,,,G,,,,,,,,,O,,,,,,,,,,G
```

Which correctly contains 10 letters and a space. But it also contains all these commas! Which are not part of my array. Why is this thing happening? Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Alex

Comment: It looks like your code got cut off. can you post more of it?

Comment: Here is the code again:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 
  var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L","M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ".", " "];

  for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){
        var random_letter = Math.floor(Math.random()*28);  
  var result=[];
  result[i] = [letters[random_letter]];
  document.write(result);
  
  }
 
</script>

Comment: and I should have said that the output contains 10 letters and a full stop, not space

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring `result` each time you iterate through the loop. If you declare it outside that should fix the problem

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L","M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ".", " "]; 

var random = [];

for (var i=0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28);
    random.push(letters[index]);
}
console.log(random);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/77vtxxjh/

#### Edit

Also your code is declaring an array of arrays instead of an array of characters. This is what was causing all the commas to print. If this is what you are actually after you can modify my code like this:

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L","M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ".", " "]; 

var random = [];
for (var j=0; j < 10; j++)
{
    var temp = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28);
        temp.push(letters[index]);
    }
    random.push(temp);
}
console.log(random);
```

And here is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/s26tvtLx/1/

Comment: Post your answer code in the answer itself and only use fiddle to demonstrate it

Comment: Thanks MrMadsen for your response. None of the above two scripts actually works. But your comment about storing the data in an array as being the cause made me go back and change the "results" variable to a string variable instead of an array. It now works.

Comment: Did you look at the fiddles I linked to? They console log all the data you're looking for.